# How to check if a command is possible before executing it in vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to use a macro to change a long long column of cells. The cells are either numbers or text. The numbers, though, are stored as text and I want to convert them. I'd like to like

```
`Range("A1").Value = Int(Range("A1").Value)`
```

, and this works fine when converting the numbers that are stored as text to number, but obviously it won't work for the values that are text and have no numbers. How do I set the command to see, if this conversion is possible then do it?

Comment: `if isNumeric(range("A1").value then` perhaps...

Answer (score 2):

Do them all at once with the [Range.TextToColumns method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193593.aspx). VBA's overhead will take care of error control.

```
with worksheets("Sheet1")
    with intersect(.usedrange, .columns(1))
        .numberformat = "General"
        .TextToColumns DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(0, 1)
    end with
end with
```

Answer (score 1):

use `IsNumeric`.  To avoid getting blanks converted to Zero, check empty too.

```
if IsNumeric(Range("A1").Value2) and Not IsEmpty(Range("A1")) then
 Range("A1").Value = Int(Range("A1").Value)
end if
```

Comment: Why do you use `Value2` in the condition and not `Value` ?

Comment: More of a habit. Gives you actual values without any interference from cell formats.

Comment: @EdwardBlack From MS docs: "The only difference between this property and the Value property is that the Value2 property doesn't use the Currency and Date data types. You can return values formatted with these data types as floating-point numbers by using the Double data type."

Comment: @LoganReed, Correct and I work with tons of finacial data daily with different timezones/ countries and currencies. So got this habit. :)

Comment: @cyboashu NP, I used it before -- but still had to look it up to remember what it does. Timezones and currencies are a nightmare - agreed.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do it:

```
With Range("A:A")  ' column A
    .NumberFormat = "General"
    .Value = .Value           ' Excel should auto convert the strings to numbers
End With
```

Comment: If there are no dates or currency in column A then **[.Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx) = [.Value2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193553.aspx)** might be marginally better.

Comment: or even better `.Value2 = .Value2` :]

Comment: Probably just programming style but I tend to use the default .Value as the target and .Value2 as the source.

Comment: @Jeeped I am pretty sure that assigning to Value2 should be a tiny bit faster but I can't test it at home.

Comment: The next time I build a couple hundred thousand rows of sample data I will test this. I **do** know that .Value2 as the source is somewhat faster just as adding **$** to explicit string functions can also save a few milliseconds.

Comment: @Jeeped `$` is short for `As String` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cz43ek.aspx

Comment: @Slai - No, *functions* that end with "$" are actually completely different functions that return a `String` instead of a `Variant` (for example `Left` "maps to" the internal `_B_var_Left` and `Left$` maps to `_B_str_Left`).  The efficiency gain comes from not having to implicitly cast back and forth from `String` to `Variant`.

Comment: @Comintern I didn't realize that Jeeped ment the VBA functions. In VBA `Function a$()` is the same as `Function a() As String` and `Function a()` is the same as `Function a() As Variant`